# Set containing multiple of both $x$ and $y$ in a certain range

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be the set which contains natural numbers which are multiples of $4$ in the range $200$ to $12000$.

Let $B$ be the set which contains natural numbers which are multiples of $100$ in the range $200$ to $12000$.

How do I find out $|A \cap B$|?

I hope the following set notation is correct for the above statements.

A = $\{x : x \epsilon \mathbb N $, $200 \leq x \leq 12000 , 4|x \}$

B = $\{x : x \epsilon \mathbb N $, $200 \leq x \leq 12000 , 100|x \}$

Looking at the smallest multiple and largest multiple, $(4)(50) =200$ and $(4)(3000)=12000$,I know $|A|= 3000-50+1 = 2951 $

Similarly, $(100)(2) =200$ and $(100)(120)=12000$, I know $|B|= 120-2 +1 = 119$

I'm not sure how to find $|A \cap B|$ from here. Are there multiple ways to do this?

EDIT:

Is there any specific way to find out the cardinality of $|A \cap B|$ if B is not a subset of A or vice versa?

Comment: Check if $B\subset A$, in which case $A\cap B = B$.

Comment: Also, $A = \left\{x: x\in {\mathbb N}, 200\le x \le 12000, x|4\right\}$ is not correct notation. The notation $x|4$ means $x$ divides $4$. You wanted $4|x$ I guess.

Comment: Yup that's right! That's what I wanted. If B is not a subset of A, then what should I do?

Comment: Your set notation, while technically correct, is not quite $\LaTeX$-correct. Use `\in` instead of `\epsilon`, and `$\{ stuff \}$` instead of putting the brackets outside of the math environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you playing with cardinalities? What do you mean "find out" $A \cap B$? You have found it just by writing it down: $A \cap B = \{x \in \mathbb N : 200 \le x \le 12000, a|x \land b|x \}$. In the particular example you've chosen, note that if something is divisible by 100, it is already divisible by 4, so $A \cap B = B$.

updating to reflect the question clarification that you only want the cardinality:
Recall that $a|x \land b|x$ if and only if $lcm(a,b)|x$. You should be able to do a concrete calculation from that.